# Grammar that contains letters a,b,c and number of letters $c$ is greater than number of letters $b$

Tags: formal-grammars

I look for grammar which use letters $a,b,c$ that numbers of letters $c$ is greater than number of letters $b$.

Example: $acbccba$

I thought about:

$$S \rightarrow aS \mid bS \mid SCS$$
$$C \rightarrow cb \mid ca$$

but not sure if it work. Could you help me, please.